# Warning citation on page 4 undefined

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

I have this warning when I tried to make a cite (Package `natbib` Warning):

> Citation `baltagi2008econometric' on page 4 undefined o n input line
>   150.

I´m using Overleaf, this is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{inputenc}  
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newgeometry{left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}}


\title{}
\begin{document}

\citep{baltagi2008econometric}
\end{document}
```

this is my bibtex

```
@book{baltagi2008econometric,
title={Econometric analysis of panel data},
  author={Baltagi, Badi},
  year={2008},
  publisher={John Wiley \& Sons}
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). If you "hate" bibtex, then just don't use it ... Could you please edit your question and change the title of your question to something that more describes the *problem* you have than your mood.

Answer (score 3):

Well, your code shows several errors. For example, you call `inputenc` three times with different options.

To me it simply looks like you copied some code from the internet without understanding what it does.  Please **only use the code you understand**!

- Do you really want to use `chapterbib`?  My best guess is you don't.
- `hyperref` should be the last called package in your case etc.

However, most importantly, your code is missing a `\bibliography` instruction.

The `\bibliography{<somefile>}` instruction serves two separate purposes:

1. You're telling BibTeX where to find the "raw" or unformatted bibliographic entries, in this case - in the file `<somefile>.bib`. *Note that one does not specify the filename extension `.bib`.* (Coupled with the information about which bibliography style one should use, BibTeX builds the formatted bibliography and places it in an external file called `\jobname.bbl`.)
2. You're telling LaTeX where in the document to insert the formatted bibliography that was assembled earlier by BibTeX. Usually, but not necessarily, the formatted bibliography is inserted toward the end of a document.

Please see the following corrected MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{baltagi2008econometric,
  title={Econometric analysis of panel data},
  author={Baltagi, Badi},
  year={2008},
  publisher={John Wiley \& Sons},
}
\end{filecontents}
 
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % <===== load this package only once
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{geometry}
\newgeometry{margin=1in}  % <==== simplified and streamlined

%\usepackage{chapterbib} % <==== commented out for now

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

\usepackage{hyperref} % <==== load this package last


%\title{} % <==== not relevant for this example
\begin{document}

\citep{baltagi2008econometric}

\bibliography{\jobname} % print bibliography created in an earlier BibTeX run
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: I've taken the liberty of rephrasing some of the explanations. Feel free to revert.